# How to store result of query (ODocument List) in orientdb graphdatabase?

Tags: graph, orientdb, tinkerpop

I am green guy in orientDB, and need some help:(
I use orientDB for storage some big graphs, and from time to time i need to use simple select query. It's works, i can get and print result of my query, but we want to store it in new graphdatabase. It's important, because we need to export this new "query"-database as graphml file for next steps of project. Can i do that? If not, why - if yes, how? :)
Here some piece of code

```
    OGraphDatabase maindatabase = new OGraphDatabase(ishod);
    OGraphDatabase resultgraphdb = new OGraphDatabase(resultname);
   maindatabase.open("admin", "admin");

    List<ODocument> resultlist = maindatabase.query(new OSQLSynchQuery("select from V limit 20"));              //It's works fine, size of this list = 20    

    for (int i = 0; i < resultlist.size(); i++) {
     //MY PROBLEMS ARE HERE - HOW TO IMPORT resultlist TO resultgraphbd

    }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can open 2 database instances and move records between databases. Just pay attention to setting the current database manually before to execute any operation:

https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/wiki/Java-Multi-Threading